# What do the curly braces mean in this variable declaration in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, variable-declaration, curly-braces

What do the curly braces do here in this variable definition?

```
const { foo } = this.bar;
```

Comment: That's called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: I suggest bookmarking [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/215552) - 90% of symbols used in TypeScript are used (or are proposed to be used) in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, your answers have been useful.  It's Destructuring!  Something that's new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript destructuring, explained here
https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-alias

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicate questions.

Comment: OK, could refrain from downvoting  as well

Comment: Thank you for answering this for me.